# Possible diskutil info protocol fields?

Tags: mac, disk-utility, bash

Is there somewhere in the OS such as a `plist` that stores all the possible protocols for `diskutil info`? So far, I have come across the internal disks as PCI, SATA and PCI-Express.

```
diskutil info /dev/disk0
   Device Identifier:         disk0
   Device Node:               /dev/disk0
   Whole:                     Yes
   Part of Whole:             disk0
   Device / Media Name:       APPLE SSD AP0512N

   Volume Name:               Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                   Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:               None

   Content (IOContent):       GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:       No
   Media Type:                Generic
   Protocol:                  PCI-Express
   SMART Status:              Verified
```

Comment: It's not clear why the drive interface (PCIe, SATA, etc.) is somehow critical to how things are configured.  What exactly is the problem you're trying to address.  As for the protocols available, issue the command `diskutil listFilesystems.`   *What's the significance of this info?*

Comment: This feels like it has already been posited, but you didn't get a satisfactory answer. Maybe we can focus on what exactly you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Are you looking for a historical list of physical interface protocols, with associated hardware interfaces, available on _every_ Mac over time? The app [MacTracker](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mactracker/id311421597) has all this spec information. Examples at my fingertips: My current (2019) iMac's internal interfaces are: 6.0 Gbps Serial ATA (SATA), 1 - 8.0 GT/s NVMe PCIe x4. The very first iMac interfaces was: ATA-3 (Shared with optical drive and hard disk drive.) _I'm neither affiliated with nor financially associated with Ian Page, the developer of MacTracker._

Answer (score 0):

I solved this a while go and will explain the problem before what I used for the solution.

Probably a lack of experience here with this component of macOS but the need was to collect disk names and serial numbers programmatically for NAID data destruction certification requirements.

Bases off of that requirement, I was using the commands `ioreg -ar -c IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice` or `ioreg -ar -c IONVMeBlockStorageDevice` which works fine for SATA and PCI-Express, but it implodes on the cylinder form factor Mac Pro's because those are PCI internally.

Since this script was running in the recovery environment, utilities like system_profiler are not available.

The solution was to go with  `ioreg -d 1 -ar -c  IOBlockStorageDevice`  I was then able to read out the just read out strings after Product Name , Serial Number for each entry having a Medium Type attribute.

Comment: Your posted answer does not answer the question you posted. Furthermore, when I enter the command `ioreg -ar -c -d 1 IOBlockStorageDevice` in macOS or macOS Recovery, I do not get any output.

Comment: your correct it should be `ioreg -d 1 -ar -c  IOBlockStorageDevice`

Comment: I still believe your posted answer does not answer the posted question. Now that you have solved your problem, I would suggest you fix this be editing both the question and answer.